# Changing available checkboxes based on dropdown option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to find a way to change the options available on a checklist based on what the user picks from a dropdown menu but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried using this [tutorial](https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/), amongst others, but can't get it to do what I want.

I have Categories, that belong to Exam Boards. I want the user to be able to select an Exam Board from a dropdown menu, which then changes which categories they see available (I want them to only see the categories that belong to that exam board).

At the moment the code in the form is (HAML):

```
= form_for @test do |f|

      .form-object
        .col-sm-12
          = f.collection_select :exam_board_id, ExamBoard.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Exam Board" }, :class => 'form-control'

      .form-object
        .col-sm-12.category_to_fix
          =# hidden_field_tag "test[category_ids][]", nil
          - Category.real.each do |category|
            -if category.year == "AS"
              .category-label
                = label_tag dom_id(category), category.name
                = check_box_tag "test[category_ids][]", category.id, @test.category_ids.include?(category.id), id: dom_id(category)

      .form-object
        = f.submit :class => 'normal button'
```

But this is just showing all the categories, not the ones related to the chosen exam board.

Is there a way I can do this with a checkbox?

Comment: Just to clarify, you say you've followed the tutorial, have you completed the steps under 'The AJAX magic'? It's the Javascript that shows and hides the checkboxes

Comment: I did that but couldn't get it to work at all -> I thought it might have something to do with the fact I am trying to fill a checkbox list, not a dropdown menu

Comment: You'll need some javascript to make the checkboxes appear/disappear without re-loading the page, there isn't another way. The code in the tutoiral just removes the contents of the `<select>` tag, and the re-populates it with new `<option>`s. It would be quite easy to make tiny changes to the Javascript so that it removes the `<input type="checkbox">` then adds new `<input type="checkbox">`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Javascript from the tutorial adjusted to remove then re-generate checkboxes. I know this won't exactly match your models and views, but without detailed structural details, I can't tell you exactly how to do that!

First, the checkboxes (and nothing else), need to be wrapped up in a `<div>`, which I've given the `id` of `cities_checkboxes`

```
<!-- app/views/cities/_city.html.erb -->
<%= f.check_box_tag :city_id, city.id %><%= city.name.titleize %>
```

Also

```
# app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js.coffee

$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#countries_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_cities',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        country_id: $("#countries_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")
```

And

```
# app/views/welcome/update_cities.js.coffee

$("#cities_checkboxes").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @cities)) %>")
```

This way, updating the country select box will load up the list of cities from the database, empty your newly-created div, which only contains the checkboxes, then add each of the checkboxes (the `_city.html.erb` partial) into that div.